# How to open a html dialog element in react using Promise?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dialog

I need to trigger a dialog with the following pseudocode. Kind of like how window.confirm() works.

```
export function Page(props){
    const handleClick = async () => {
       // This function call should trigger a dialogModal.
       const response = await modal.open({
           title: "Please fill the form",
           type: "Warning",
       })
       if(response === "YES"){
           // Do the action
       }
       else if(response === "CANCEL"){
          modal.dismiss()
       }
    }
    return <button onclick={handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
}
```

Below will be my modal psuedocode

```
export function Modal(props){
   // functionality here
    return (
    <dialog>
        <button>Yes</button>
        <button>Cancel</button>    
    </dialog>)
}
```

I am pretty sure I can get away with using a state to manage the hide/show of modal, but seems like this approach is cleaner. But I don't know any idea how to get started.

Basically I need to trigger a html dialog element, and wait for the result, Just like a window.confirm() waits for the result of the user.

The reason for Promise is that, when the modal opens, it will be waiting for the user's input, and when the user presses any button in the modal, the promise will be resolved. The promise's result will probably be a key to detect which button user has pressed in the modal.

Comment: Please see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) related to this.

Comment: *I just need something to get started on this* is too broad of a question, but I would advise against this approach. Use state instead of promises, there are a dozen edge cases that you will encounter if you go against the React way of doing it with state

Comment: @VirajShah not sure what that has to do with this question..

Comment: @VirajShah Please review my question, before putting out a comment, I have asked to trigger a modal with a promise and wait for the result.

Comment: @VirajShah  The question is specifically about React & state not the dialog element.

Comment: *"I am pretty sure I can get away with using a state to manage the hide/show of modal"* - That's exactly how you'd do this in React.  Use state to track the "current state" of the interface, and use events (clicks, etc.) to update that state.  It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish by trying to avoid that.

Comment: I know exactly what the question is asking – there is absolutely no reason you would every require a `Promise` to achieve this. Additionally, the OP provided "pseudocode", and is asking a very trivial question that is easily found in the documentation. ReactJS is not a different language than JavaScript, so the JavaScript solution works the exact same

Comment: @VirajShah I already KNOW how to open a dialog. I don't need the web API documentation for that. The reason for promise is that, when the modal opens, it will be waiting for the user's input, and when the user presses any button in the modal, the promise will be resolved.

Comment: @Aslam: *"when the modal opens, it will be waiting for the user's input"* - Conceptually, yes.  But you're thinking about it the wrong way.  You don't want to actually make the code **wait**.  Update the state of the component to display the modal.  When the user presses a button in the modal, that's another state update, hiding the modal and updating whatever other state is produced by clicking the button.  It sounds like you're getting caught up in the semantic meaning of "waiting" and overthinking the approach.  All of this is simply driven by updating state.

Comment: @David, I think I am overthinking, I had a modal framework in my previous job that would do exactly this, it would wait for the promise to resolve while waiting for user input on the modal. I was thinking of doing the exact thing here, it was using vanilla JS, Probably I am not thinking in react enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using state is the way to go here, you can then capture a resolve from a promise constructor, and you can then wait on this.

Below is an example, `createAtom` is a simple global state manager I created, but you can use any state manager you wish, eg.  jotai

ps:  Stack Overflows babel compiler needs updating, you can't have JSX & async / await, so the example is using thenables.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const dialogOpen = createAtom(false);
const info = createAtom('');

let dialogResolve;

function Dialog() {
  const {use} = dialogOpen;
  return <dialog open={use()}>
    <button onClick={() => { 
       dialogResolve('Yes');
       dialogOpen.setValue(false);
    }}>Yes</button>
    <button onClick={() => {
       dialogResolve('Cancel');
       dialogOpen.setValue(false);
    }}>Cancel</button> 
  </dialog>
}

function Info() {
  const txt = info.use();
  return <div>{txt}</div>
}

function modal() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    dialogOpen.setValue(true);
    dialogResolve = resolve;
  });
}

function Test() {
  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => {
      modal().then(r => info.setValue(
        "You clicked " + r + ' @ ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
      ))
    }}>Test</button>
  </div>
}

function Main() {
  return <React.Fragment>
    <Test/>
    <br/>
    <Info/>
    <Dialog/>
  </React.Fragment>;
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Main/>);

function createAtom(_def) {
  const evt = new EventTarget();
  let _value = _def;
  function use() {
    const [, _refresher] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
      evt.addEventListener('notify', () => {
        _refresher(c => c + 1);
      });
    }, []);
    return _value;
  } 
  function setValue(v) {
    _value = v;
    evt.dispatchEvent(new Event('notify'));
  }
  const value = () => _value;
  return {value, setValue, use};
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: why do you need a state manager and what does it do ? If I simply use useSTate() for both dialogOpen and info , clicking the yes/no button causes the error "dialogResolve is not a function" which means its not getting set or it gets rerendered to  undefined again ?

Comment: @MayureshGaitonde  React's state is only really component state, if you try and use it for application state, it starts to become very complicated & fragile.  That doesn't mean React's state is bad, it's good that it's kept simple, because what people like for state can be very personal, eg. a lot of people like Redux, me personally not a fan, something like Recoil or better still Jotai.  A good state manager also make it easy to keep React's renders more granular, and doing that keeps performance high, maybe not as high as say SolidJS, but not far off.